# Original Markup inInternet Explorer in Range / Selection

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, selection, markup

I am extracting content selected by the user via this function:

```
 function getSelectionHTML() {

  var userSelection;
  if (window.getSelection)
  {

   // W3C Ranges
   userSelection = document.getElementById('axPage').contentWindow.getSelection();
   // Get the range:
   if (userSelection.getRangeAt)
    var range = userSelection.getRangeAt (0);
   else
   {
    var range = document.createRange ();
     range.setStart (userSelection.anchorNode, userSelection.anchorOffset);
     range.setEnd (userSelection.focusNode, userSelection.focusOffset);
   }

   var clonedSelection = range.cloneContents ();
   var div = document.createElement ('div');
   div.appendChild (clonedSelection);
   return div.innerHTML;

  }
  else if (document.selection)
  {
userSelection = self.frames['axPage'].document.selection.createRange();
   return userSelection.htmlText;
  }
  else
  {

   return '';

  }

  };
```

Extraction is working fine, but I do not seem to find a way to get the original markup of the selected text in Internet Explorer. Is there any way to get a DocumentFragment like in Firefox? I know about the different handling and approach of both systems, but maybe someone has found a working approach in javascript / ECMA to get rid of the nasty ...jQueryXXXXXXXXXXXXX="12" addons in HREFs and that painful uppercase tag- and attributenames.

Again: it is essential to get the exact markup selected.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your help, I finally figured it out. If you need to get selected text in Internet Explorer with tags to lower-case try this http://codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=148450 function and if you use jquery and have nasty little .jQueryXXXXXXXXXXXXX="12" 13, 14 right after every single href=""-closing " your solution is to copy your markup to a div and read its innerHTML.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

Your only options in IE are writing code to walk the DOM between the selection boundary points or using `htmlText` from the selection TextRange as you are doing. The first option will be pretty involved. I don't really understand what your problem is with the second approach: could you be more precise or give an example of what's wrong with the HTML you get from htmlText?